# moving file pointer after reading a line from a file

Tags: file, bash, unix, loops

```
while read line;do
read header_line < headers.txt
task 1
task 2
done < temp1.txt
```

I want to be reading lines from files headers.txt and temp1.txt simultaneously. So, for eg if i read a line from temp1.txt, i should also read a line from headers.txt. Problem with this code is that it reads the lines from temp1.txt one by one but it keeps reading the same line from headers.txt. I want the file pointer to move to the next line once header_line is read. How do i go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can replace this line

```
read header_line < headers.txt
```

with :

```
 sed -n '${count}p' hearders.txt
```

where count is incremented in each iteration in the while loop and should be initialized to 1.

Comment: and if i want to store the sed output in a variable? and will count variable be incremented automatically? im a newbie in unix :D @peter

Comment: sed -n "${count}p" headers.txt. Should be double quotes

Answer (score 3):

Use an extra file descriptor and do the second read before the `do`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# open extra file descriptors for input
exec 3< headers.txt

while read -r line; read -r -u 3 header_line
do
    echo "[$header_line] [$line]"
done < temp1.txt

# close the extra file descriptor
exec 3<&-
```